# Polygons disappearing

Tags: leaflet

I am working on a site with leaflet functionality. On the initial map a set of points (markers), lines and polygons are added to the map. But when zooming into the map the polygons disappear and does not reappear in zooming out. Someties I can make them randomly appear when panning a bit, sometimes they do not disappear until panning... It's kind of random which makes it even more strange.
The testsite is here: https://udvikling2.qler.dk/test/hg
Does anyone have an idea what's going on? Googling revealed some rather old posts, but found nothing useful. Enabling "preferCanvas" for the map does not fix the problem.

Thank you!

Regards
Morten, Denmark

Comment: Your demo code showing me the layers after zooming. Have your tried this on a different browser? Which Browser are you using?

Comment: Using Chrome, but tested in FF as well and result was the same... both fully updated. Thats really strange. Just tested in an incognity tab as well, if some plugin was interferring, but stille the red areas disappear randomly.

Comment: Did a short video showing the problem:https://www.dropbox.com/s/78032c8wt1bha50/VID_20210121_154535.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Yeah I can reproduce. The problem is that something is changing the `d` attribute of the  `path` maybe one of your libraries?

Comment: Stripped the page from everything but leaflet, and the problem remains...
https://udvikling2.qler.dk/test/hg

Comment: this is not valid html, missing stuff, I know, but issue remains...

Comment: OK, this was strange, but ended up finding an old thread somewhere which confirmed that if the style of a polygon has "weight" set to a string value like: "{weight:'3'}, this random behavior can occur... removing the single quotes seem to have solved the issue for now.

Comment: This is really weird

Answer (score 3):

This is a Leaflet Bug.

This only happens when the "weight" of the polygon is a string: `{weight: "10"}`

The problem in leaflet is that it do some calculations with the weight and then while adding the weight to a value it is not calculated correct: `3 + "10" = "310"` and not `13`

I created a PR for this issue: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/7432

Comment: You're a legend! This resolves the problem.